# How do I use my ip in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a setup a SQL Server instance that I can see from all the computers in the network... which means it is configured correctly for remote access. (192,168.0.50).

The server is bound to an ip address 65.xx.xx.xx

I can see a website that I host on it from IIS, and when I ping it it give the static address.

When I try to connect to the SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio... using that address 65.xx.xx.xx, 1433 it will not connect!

[SQL configuration][1]..

Should I be seeing my static address in the properties...of the connection ??

Comment: have you bound the server to the 65.x.x.x address? it could be bound to only the 192 one, which is non-routeable and won't be available remotely from another network.

Comment: Do you have the proper ports open on the 65.xx address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not easy to connect to network from internet
because it behind a router and firewall

a tutorial to access your sql instance

http://lifehacker.com/127276/geek-to-live--how-to-access-a-home-server-behind-a-routerfirewall

Comment: it's a remote server, so i will have to get router details from the admin, will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to it from within the network, try using the local network IP.

Also remember to include the instance name in the connection string if you set your instance up as a named instance.

Example 192.168.0.50\instanceName

Answer (score 0):

> I can see a website that I host on it from IIS, and when I ping it it give the static address.

Just because you can see a website, and can ping the static address, doesn't mean that the firewall between the server and the internet is configured to allow traffic to pass on the 1433 port.

Your router admin will need to map port 1433 inbound to the 65.x.x.x address and then using NAT (Network Address Translation) point it to the internal IP Address 192.168.0.50.

This is the same thing that is being done for the IIS website that you mention, only in this case the port would be 80, or possibly 443 to allow HTTPS traffic through.

Comment: Thank-you, once i forwared the port to the remote machine.. IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) , and when you are ok with the internal Network Configurations, 
you need to check the Router configuration to allow port forward connections. Every Router has its own config.

For example :

1. Open SQL Server Network Utility, set the TCP/IP Enabled and set a PORT to use.
2. If you have a Router (Port Forward the IP of your PC where your SQL Server is Installed)
3. Now if your Internet IP is STATIC (Use DDNS service of your router) and if your Internet IP is DYNAMIC (Proceed to next step)
4. Now after doing step 1-3 your SQL Server already has an internet connectivity so you must go to the Client PC from which you want to use (sample your server is Office PC and your client is your Home PC) OPEN "CLIENT NETWORK UTILITY"
5. Open Alias TAB, Click ADD, Enter your SERVER ALIAS (Any name you want to use)
6. In Network Libraries select TCP/IP
7. In Connection Parameters - Server name = (your servers internet IP address)
8. Click Dynamically determine port and ENTER THE PORT # (the port you set from router)
9. Basically where done... OPEN SQL Server Manager then Register your DATABASE!

Hope it helps !!